# Scale Textview FontSize to specific amount of characters per line

Tags: android

I want to have a textview which only allows 16 characters per line, but uses the whole width of the textview.
By trying out different values, I found out that fontSize = 23sp worked on a 480x800 screen but not on other screen resolutions.

How can I scale the fontsize so there will be maximum 16 characters per line on any screen?

Greetings

Comment: Eventually you could try using "dp" (or "dip", is the same), not "sp". DIP -> Density-independent pixels. SP -> scale-independent pixels

Comment: Here is link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: Sry, I actually used dp not sp. The AutoResizer is not the thing I am looking for because it should not resize the size with the text, it should always be the same size but only allow 16 characters on every screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this may be it helps you and check the size of text view for screen.**

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int Displaywidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int Displayheight = metrics.heightPixels;


        if (Displaywidth <= 480 && Displayheight <= 800) {

                    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,23);
        }

        else if (Displaywidth <= 720 && Displayheight <= 1280) {


              text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,30);

        }

        else {
             text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,30);


        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works pretty well. But is there a formula to adjust the font size or do I have to go through all the resolutions?

Comment: there is not any specific formula for size of text only for 16char.